# Merging two rows of a table based on same column existence

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Assuming I have a table below:

```
<pre>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>id</b></td>
            <td><b>name</b></td>
            <td><b>rank</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Ohio</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</pre>
```

Where the **id** column relates all the rows.

How can I merge all the rows having the same **id** value together and the **rank** column will be the average of all the rows being merged.

E.g the result will look like the table below:

```
<pre>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>id</b></td>
            <td><b>name</b></td>
            <td><b>rank</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Ohio</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</pre>
```

Where 4 in the **rank** column is the  **average sum of all the rows merge in the first table**

**Note:**  
Each row is an array taken from a 2D array. Therefore the result must be a 2D array.

Using SQL is just too hard as this table comprises of 4 other tables from the database. So I'd prefer the answer in PHP or JavaScript

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT id, name, avg(rank) FROM table GROUP BY id, name;
```

The key here is the [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

As you said your table is created by joining four tables you can use it with a subselect:

```
SELECT id, name, avg(rank) FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM whatver --here goes your statement joining the four tables
) 
GROUP BY id, name;
```

Comment: Thanks I'd worked around the issue before now and it's working. But I'll try your solution to add more knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, AVG( rank ) AS `rank` FROM table_name GROUP BY `id`, `name`
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,NAME,AVG([RANK])[RANK] FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID,NAME
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code-only answer.  When new users see high-repped users posting code-only solutions, they think this is "the right thing to do here".  Please show new users that every answer deserves an explanation.